# Deleting public methods in Javascript modules after one use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I've been using the Javascript module pattern recently, and all of it makes crystal clear sense to me except for one thing: preventing public methods from being called more than once.

For instance, I may have some javascript that runs on page load that is a public method on the module that sets up buttons and actions, as well as determining visibility of elements, etc. I don't want someone to be able to call that code a second time because it could wreck the intended look and functionality of the page, and quite frankly, I can't think of a reason why I would want anyone to even know the method exists after the first call.

One way to achieve this functionality would be to have a private boolean tracking whether these public methods were called, then the next time through, bail instead of executing. This is fairly common in every programming language, and could be accomplished as seen below.

```
var Module = (function() {
    var _showHelloWorld = function() {
        jQuery('div').text('Hello World!');
    },

    _init = function() {
        if (_initCalled) {
            console.log('Init was already called!');
            return;
        }

        _showHelloWorld();

        _initCalled = true;
    },

    _initCalled = false;

    return {
        init : _init
    };
})();

jQuery(function() {
    Module.init();

    // This will not break, it will log that init was called already and bail!
    Module.init();
});
```

However, the public function remains in such a situation, and even though future calls to the method would effectively do nothing, the method still sticks around for people to see if they dig around in the console, etc.

The root of my question is, why not just delete these sorts of public methods from the module after they're called? Is there a reason we wouldn't want to do this? I tried to search the web for discussions on this sort of situation, but I haven't found anything related to the topic. The following code attempts to explain my idea:

```
var Module = (function() { 
    var _showHelloWorld = function() {
        jQuery('div').text('Hello World!');
    },

    _init = function() {
        _showHelloWorld();

        // LOOK HERE!
        delete this.init;
        // LOOK HERE!
    };

    return {
        init : _init
    };
})();

jQuery(function() {
    Module.init();

    // THIS IS GOING TO BREAK!
    Module.init();
});
```

After the first call to the init method, we could just delete the public method and not worry about it anymore.

Can anyone tell me why this is a bad idea or why it shouldn't be done? I'm sure this is a silly question, but I can't find any resources on the topic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Self-modifying code is a BAD idea

Comment: You can certainly do that, but it won't do a thing to keep your code hidden from prying eyes.

Comment: @ControlAltDel , would using the boolean method to track be the most correct way to do this then?

Comment: Sometimes you need a boolean. Other times you can just tell from some other variable you changed in the first iteration. And it's totally legitimate to throw an Exception if the method is called a second time if it shouldn't be

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, there are four ways of solving the problem of allowing a function to be invoked only once

1. Using a boolean flag to mark that the function has executed (mentioned in the original post). This technique is language agnostic. You'll especially want to use this if other functions depend on your  `init()` function having to run first.
2. Use Underscore's [once](http://underscorejs.org/#once) to create a function that can only be run once. This has the advantage of not creating a boolean if you don't need it.
3. Modify the function by deleting it (mentioned in the original post). This works but seems like a bad idea. Your `init()` callers have to keep track of whether or not `init()` has already been called in order to avoid a null reference error.
4. Modify the function be replacing it with a noop. This has exactly the same pros and cons as using Underscore's once. So, instead of
   `delete this.init`

do

```
this.init = function(){};
```

Thus, in my opinion, 1,2,4 are good options in JavaScript.